# Save NSMutableData representing an image to the iPhone photo library

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, exif

I have a NSMutableData containing a JPEG that I want to save in the device library.

I can do it converting it to an UIImage, but then it loses the EXIF data, so UIImaes should be avoided.

**EDIT** To reflect what I am trying to accomplish

I am using the [iphone-exif library](http://code.google.com/p/iphone-exif/)  to edit the metadata of a picture in my main bundle. I want to save the resulting image in the photo library

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"P1080330" ofType:@"JPG"];  
NSData *uiJpeg = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];  
EXFJpeg* jpegScanner = [[EXFJpeg alloc] init];
[jpegScanner scanImageData: uiJpeg];
NSLog(@" EXIF_Make   %@ ", [ jpegScanner.exifMetaData tagValue: [NSNumber numberWithInt:EXIF_Make]]); // OUTPUTS PANASONIC

// Change camera maker to FairyGodmother
[jpegScanner.exifMetaData addTagValue: @"FairyGodmother" forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:EXIF_Make]];

NSMutableData *newImageData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
[jpegScanner populateImageData:newImageData];

// NOW I HAVE THE NSMUTABLEDATA CONTAINGING MY IMAGE WITH ALL MY EXIF DATA. HOW DO I PUT IT TO THE PHOTO LIBRARY?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum` (which takes a UIImage) is the only documented path to getting an image in the device's photo library, as far as I know.

What is your concern with "losing EXIF data"? Are you talking about orientation? (UIImage should take care of that for you.) Or other EXIF data?

The only way you can get an image **out** of the photo library is as a UIImage also, so I'm not sure what you stand to gain by shoving a raw JPEG stream into the library.

Comment: I am talking about all the EXIF data that a Jpeg can contain: Orientation, location data, exposure time, software used, copyright... it looks like that UIImage strips all that data, this is why I would like to avoid using it. According to what you say, that's not possible :\

Answer (score -1):

To Write a File use:

```
[yourImage writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

[]'s

Comment: Unless you can write directly to the sandbox of the iOS photo library, which you can't, this isn't going to work.